# **Refactored** Library project

Tags: javascript, object-oriented, mvc

**My Solution**

What I am looking for:

1. DRY Code - in my handleDeleteBook and handleToggleStatus methods I felt that I couldn't find a way to share the id between the methods. Furthermore, what other sections of the code need to be DRY?
2. MVC Pattern - this was my first time using the MVC pattern so I don't know if I did it correctly and also I used OOJS for this but I don't know if I should've used factories and modules.
3. Better code - what code could be better? For example, II think I could've used a closure for my generateBookComponent but instead, I wipe the book components from the DOM and render them again so I don't have duplicates in the DOM.

**Disclaimer**

I did get my library project reviewed before but I wanted to see how much I improved.

```js
const Model = function() {
 this.books = [];
};

Model.prototype.addBook = function(
 bookTitle,
 bookAuthor,
 bookPage,
 bookStatus
) {
 const book = {
  id:
   this.books.length > 0
    ? this.books[this.books.length - 1].id + 1
    : 0,
  title: bookTitle,
  author: bookAuthor,
  page: bookPage,
  status: bookStatus,
 };

 this.books.push(book);
};

Model.prototype.deleteBook = function(id) {
 return (this.books = this.books.filter(bookId => bookId.id !== id));
};

Model.prototype.toggleStatus = function(id, updatedText) {
 return (this.books[id].status = updatedText);
};

const View = function() {
 this.modal = document.querySelector('.modal');

 this.statusText = {
  read: 'Read',
  unread: 'Unread',
 };
};

View.prototype.InputValues = function() {
 return {
  titleInput: document.getElementById('title').value,
  authorInput: document.getElementById('author').value,
  currentPage: Number(document.getElementById('pages').value),
  statusOption: document.getElementById('status').value,
 };
};

View.prototype.resetInput = function() {
 document
  .querySelectorAll('.modal__input')
  .forEach(input =>
   input.value !== '' ? (input.value = '') : input.value
  );
};

View.prototype.setModal = function(stateModal) {
 if (stateModal) {
  this.modal.style.display = 'flex';
 } else {
  this.modal.style.display = 'none';
 }
};

View.prototype.toggleStatus = function() {
 if (event.target.textContent === this.statusText.read) {
  event.target.classList.remove('status__btn--change');
  event.target.textContent = this.statusText.unread;
 } else {
  event.target.classList.toggle('status__btn--change');
  event.target.textContent = this.statusText.read;
 }

 return event.target.textContent;
};

View.prototype.deleteBook = function() {
 event.target.parentNode.parentNode.remove();
};

View.prototype.getId = function() {
 return Number(event.target.parentNode.parentNode.dataset.id);
};

View.prototype.generateBookComponent = function(library) {
 let htmlTemplate = library.map(library => {
  return `
            <tr class="bookshelf__book" data-id="${library.id}">
                <td class="title">${library.title}</td><td class="author">${
   library.author
  }</td><td class="pages">${
   library.page
  }</td><td class="status"><button class="${
   library.status === 'Read'
    ? 'status__btn status__btn--change'
    : 'status__btn'
  }" >${
   library.status === this.statusText.read
    ? this.statusText.read
    : this.statusText.unread
  }</button></td><td class="delete"><button class="btn btn--primary">x</button></td>
            </tr>`;
 });
 return htmlTemplate.join('');
};

View.prototype.clearBooksDom = function() {
 const bookshelf = document.querySelectorAll('.bookshelf__book');
 bookshelf.forEach(bookHTML => bookHTML.remove());
};

View.prototype.render = function(component) {
 const bookshelf = document.querySelector('.bookshelf__creation');
 bookshelf.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', component);
};

const Controller = function(Model, View) {
 this.Model = Model;
 this.View = View;
};

const app = new Controller(new Model(), new View());

Controller.prototype.handleAddBook = function() {
 const {
  titleInput,
  authorInput,
  currentPage,
  statusOption,
 } = this.View.InputValues();
 this.Model.addBook(titleInput, authorInput, currentPage, statusOption);
};

Controller.prototype.handleDeleteBook = function() {
 let id = this.View.getId();
 this.View.deleteBook();
 this.Model.deleteBook(id);
};

Controller.prototype.handleToggleStatus = function() {
 let id = this.View.getId();
 let status = this.View.toggleStatus();
 this.Model.toggleStatus(id, status);
};

Controller.prototype.handleModal = function(state) {
 this.View.setModal(state);
 this.View.resetInput();
};

Controller.prototype.startRender = function() {
 const bookComponent = this.View.generateBookComponent(this.Model.books);
 this.View.clearBooksDom();
 this.View.render(bookComponent);
};

document
 .querySelector('.bookshelf__open-modal')
 .addEventListener('click', () => {
  // - invoke handleModal()
  app.handleModal(true);
 });

document.querySelector('.modal__add').addEventListener('click', event => {
 // - grab input values from array and store in book array
 app.handleAddBook();

 // - modal is gone
 app.handleModal(false);

 // - render books from book array
 app.startRender();
});

document.querySelector('.modal__cancel').addEventListener('click', () => {
 app.handleModal(false);
});

window.addEventListener('click', event => {
 if (event.target.classList.contains('btn--primary')) app.handleDeleteBook();

 if (event.target.classList.contains('status__btn')) app.handleToggleStatus();
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
          box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}

.background {
  padding: 2% 4%;
  margin-bottom: 2em;
  height: 12rem;
  width: 100%;
  color: #fff;
  background: linear-gradient(304deg, #020024 0%, #3a3d3d 0%, #282828 94%);
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
      -ms-flex-direction: column;
          flex-direction: column;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
      -ms-flex-pack: center;
          justify-content: center;
}

.background__heading {
  margin-bottom: 0.2em;
  font-size: 2.5rem;
}

.bookshelf {
  max-width: 90%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
}

.bookshelf__heading {
  font-size: 2rem;
  font-weight: 700;
}

.bookshelf__creation {
  text-align: left;
}

.bookshelf table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  margin: 2em 0;
}

.bookshelf table th {
  padding: 0.6em 1em;
}

.bookshelf__book {
  border-top: 2px solid #ececec;
}

.bookshelf__book td {
  padding: 1em;
  text-align: left;
}

.bookshelf__open-modal {
  padding: 0.7rem;
  border: none;
  background-color: #383838;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
}

.status__btn {
  padding: 0.4rem 2rem;
  border: none;
  background-color: #ececec;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.status__btn--change {
  background-color: #383838;
  color: white;
}

.delete .btn {
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 1.5rem;
  height: 1.5rem;
  color: white;
  border-radius: 50%;
  text-align: center;
  border: none;
  font-weight: 700;
  -webkit-transition: background-color 0.5s ease-in-out;
  transition: background-color 0.5s ease-in-out;
}

.delete .btn:hover {
  background-color: #383838;
}

.modal {
  padding: 1.25rem;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  background: white;
  max-width: 50%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  -webkit-transform: translate(50%, 20%);
          transform: translate(50%, 20%);
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
      -ms-flex-align: center;
          align-items: center;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
      -ms-flex-pack: center;
          justify-content: center;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
      -ms-flex-direction: column;
          flex-direction: column;
  border-radius: 6px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0.5em 1em -0.125em rgba(10, 10, 10, 0.1), 0 0 0 1px rgba(10, 10, 10, 0.02);
          box-shadow: 0 0.5em 1em -0.125em rgba(10, 10, 10, 0.1), 0 0 0 1px rgba(10, 10, 10, 0.02);
  color: #4a4a4a;
  display: none;
}

.modal .modal__add {
  padding: 0.7rem;
  border: none;
  background-color: #383838;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.modal .modal__cancel {
  padding: 0.7rem;
  border: 1.5px solid lightgray;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.modal h2 {
  margin-bottom: 1em;
}

.modal * {
  -ms-flex-item-align: self-start;
      -ms-grid-row-align: self-start;
      align-self: self-start;
}

.modal label {
  font-size: 1rem;
  font-weight: 600;
  margin-bottom: 0.4em;
}

.modal input {
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
  height: 3em;
  border: 1.5px solid lightgray;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.modal select {
  width: 6rem;
  height: 2rem;
  border: 1.5px solid lightgray;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: #fff;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
  cursor: pointer;
}

tbody:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: whitesmoke;
  border-top: 1px solid #a0a0a0;
}
/*# sourceMappingURL=index.css.map */
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
        <title>Librario</title>

        <!-- links -->
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="./index.css">
    </head>

    <body>

        <div class="container">
            <header class="background">
                <h1 class="background__heading">Librario</h1>
                <p class="background__intro-text">Your Pocket Bookshelf</p>
            </header>

            <div class="bookshelf">
                <h2 class="bookshelf__heading">Books</h2>

                <table class="bookshelf__creation">
                    
                    <tr class="table">
                        <th class="table__heading">Title</th>
                        <th class="table__heading">Author</th>
                        <th class="table__heading">Pages</th>
                        <th class="table__heading">Status</th>
                    </tr>

                    <!-- <!-- <tr class="bookshelf__book" data-newBook="">
                        <td class="title">Harry Potter and the Sorceror Stone</td>
                        <td class="author">J.K Rowling</td>
                        <td class="pages">890</td>
                        <td class="status"><button class="status__btn">Read</button></td>
                        <td class="delete"><button class="btn btn--primary">x</button></td>
                    </tr> -->
                    
                </table>

                <button class="bookshelf__open-modal">Add New Book</button>
            </div>

            <div class="modal">
                <h2>Add New Book</h2>
                <label for="title">Title</label>
                <input class="modal__input" id="title" type="text">
                
                <label for="author">Author</label>
                <input class="modal__input" id="author" type="text">
                
                <label for="pages">Number of Pages</label>
                <input class="modal__input" id="pages" type="text">

                <label for="status">Read Status</label>
                <select  id="status">
                    <option value="Read">Read</option>
                    <option value="Unread">Unread</option>
                </select>

                <div class="modal__btn-container">
                    <button class="modal__add">Add Book</button>
                    <button class="modal__cancel">Cancel</button>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>

        <!-- Scripts -->
        <script src="./index.js"></script>
    </body>

</html>
```